# Show/Hide Divs dynamically in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have 5 divs on my page. When my form is loaded, all 5 divs gets populated with some data. However, I have to display only 3 div at a time and when user takes any action or clicks on cross(X) sign on 
any div, we have to display next div.

**Need to figure out how to display only 3 records i.e. only 3 div ?
At a time max 3 divs can be displayed**

```
    //Model
export class Bird{
 id: number;
 name: string;

}

This is the sample collection that we need to display in DIV on form
arrBirds: Birds [] = [
    { id:1, name: 'Bells Sparrow' },
    { id:2, name: 'Mourning Dove'},
    { id:3, name: 'Bald Eagle' },
    { id:4, name: 'Sparrow' }
    { id:5, name: 'Parrot' }
  ];


//html
This is how, I am displaying the data in DIV on form.
<div *ngFor='let bird of arrBirds' (click)="onSelection(bird)">
    <div>{{ bird.name }}</div>
</div>

// this code is to take any action on what user has selected in div
<div *ngIf="selectedBird">
 {{selectedBird.id}} {{selectedBird.name}}
</div>

// 
onSelection(userSelectedBird: Bird}{
 this.selectedBird = userSelectedBird;
}
```

Comment: please post your code or create a stackbliz

Comment: @PatricioVargas - Added code per your comments, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define array of pages with 'active' state, i.e

```
const pages = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'page1'
  active: true
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'page2'
  active: true
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'page3'
  active: true
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'page4'
  active: false
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'page5'
  active: false
}]
```

Based on selection, you can set active flag true/false. You can use active Property with *ngIf in the Template file.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxzrlp

Comment: Thanks for pointers.. beginners like me need pointers ... this worked... only thing now I am looking for is - how to set the reminder to true ? as only 3 can be displayed... if user has more then 3 pages... and if clicks on page 1, page 1 goes off... but page 4 should come up.. and then 5 and so on... need few more pointers pls...